# How can I create fastly, with numpy an asociation of two vectors, one for indices of the second and other for booleans?

Tags: python, numpy

is my first question here, and I don't know how call it, so...

I have a numpy vector of "groups" int, like:

```
g = [2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

I have a numpy vector of "visible" boolean, like:

```
v = [True, False, True, False, False]
```

"v" has a size representing maximum number of groups (ex: 0 to 4)

"g" has indices that can't exced the limits of "v" (ex: 0 to 4)
but not necesarily has all the indices of "v" (ex: don't 0)
in size "g" can be different to "v", like in exmple.

so I need a new vector that pass booleans to "g" like:

```
b = [T, F, F, T, F, F, F, T, F, F]
```

I can make it with a for, but I need speed, some idea?

Comment: You just want `v[g]`, as long as `v` is an ndarray

Comment: Could you please add your first approach of the code?, probably you'd receive more help if so.